# Parsing a JSON array with a Dictionary.ValueCollection

Tags: c#, arrays, json, dictionary

I'm struggling with the nested / valuecollection element of my Dictionary from a JSON file. From my research on stackoverflow there are examples of standard JSON files but not arrays.  I'm writing this in Unity3D and using C# so I am limited to .NET 2.0 framework and using MiniJSON to parse JSON but the bit I really don't get is to how to iterate through the items and add to a List or Dictionary of my custom class.

Where I have got to is:

My JSON file

```
{ 
    "circle": [
    {
        "density": 2, "friction": 0, "bounce": 0, 
        "filter": { "categoryBits": 1, "maskBits": 65535 },
        "shape": [   148.5, 91  ,  144.5, 104  ,  58, 148.5  ,  45, 144.5  ,  64, -0.5  ,  65, -0.5  ,  144.5, 45  ,  149.5, 63  ]
    },
    {
        "density": 2, "friction": 0, "bounce": 0, 
        "filter": { "categoryBits": 1, "maskBits": 65535 },
        "shape": [   58, 148.5  ,  144.5, 104  ,  117, 137.5  ,  104, 144.5  ,  86, 149.5  ]
    },
    {
        "density": 2, "friction": 0, "bounce": 0, 
        "filter": { "categoryBits": 1, "maskBits": 65535 },
        "shape": [   0.5, 58  ,  4.5, 45  ,  64, -0.5  ,  45, 144.5  ,  11.5, 117  ,  4.5, 104  ,  -0.5, 86  ]
    },
    {
        "density": 2, "friction": 0, "bounce": 0, 
        "filter": { "categoryBits": 1, "maskBits": 65535 },
        "shape": [   134, 27.5  ,  140.5, 37  ,  144.5, 45  ,  65, -0.5  ,  86, -0.5  ,  95, 1.5  ,  104, 4.5  ,  121, 14.5  ]
    },
    {
        "density": 2, "friction": 0, "bounce": 0, 
        "filter": { "categoryBits": 1, "maskBits": 65535 },
        "shape": [   64, -0.5  ,  4.5, 45  ,  11.5, 32  ,  32, 11.5  ,  45, 4.5  ]
    },
    {
        "density": 2, "friction": 0, "bounce": 0, 
        "filter": { "categoryBits": 1, "maskBits": 65535 },
        "shape": [   117, 137.5  ,  144.5, 104  ,  137.5, 117  ]
    },
    {
        "density": 2, "friction": 0, "bounce": 0, 
        "filter": { "categoryBits": 1, "maskBits": 65535 },
        "shape": [   11.5, 117  ,  45, 144.5  ,  32, 137.5  ]
    }
]
}
```

and I am opening and parsing the root element "circles" as follows within my C# class.  This essentially gets the text file from my folder and loads to an initial Dictionary:

```
TextAsset jsonTextAsset = Resources.Load(_dataPath, typeof(TextAsset)) as TextAsset; 

Dictionary<string, object> dict = jsonTextAsset.text.dictionaryFromJson();

Debug.Log ("Count: " + dict.Count);
```

The count shows me I have my 1 root element.  Also if I check via the debugger I see 7 item collections, 6 of those shown in the JSON file and an empty item.

The bit I don't get is how do I get hold of it.

I created the following class to potentially create a custom List or Dictionary type:

```
public class FPObject 
{
    public int Density { get; set; }
    public int Friction { get; set; }
    public int Bounce { get; set; }
    public int CategoryBits { get; set; }
    public int MaskBits { get; set; }
    public double[] Shape { get; set; }
}
```

I feel I am close but I'm not experienced enough with JSON nor Dictionaries to finish this off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the correct classes I hope the following code helps you:

**Note:** I used [JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json) instead of MiniJSON.

```cs
    public class RootJson
    {
        public List<Circle> CircleList { get; set; }
    }

    public class Circle
    {
        public int Density { get; set; }
        public int Friction { get; set; }
        public int Bounce { get; set; }
        public Filter CategoryBits { get; set; }
        public List<double> Shape { get; set; }
    }

    public class Filter
    {
        public int CategoryBits { get; set; }
        public int MaskBits { get; set; }
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"JsonFilePath");
        RootJson JCircle = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootJson>(Json);
        Debug.Print(JCircle.CircleList.Count.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much while your answer wasnt 100% what I required because i cant use JSON.NET in unity I did resolve.  I dumped MiniJSON as it couldnt handle object deserialisation but instead went for **litJSON** as it was AOT compliant for iOS devices.  Not only that but used **http://json2csharp.com/** to ensure my class was correct as @Deja Vu suggested.